# Java Swing - how to carry out a one-time task with a timer?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I can't figure out the best way to do this.

So my program is a game, and the user must "eat" to decrease their hunger. So when a JButton is pressed, I am planning on the hunger to decrease by 10 every second, for 10 seconds. During this time, the JProgressBar decreases and no other action can be carried out within the program.

I know how to do a repeating timer, but I am not sure how to do a one-time timer like this, and would really appreciate some guidance.

Many thanks.

Comment: You can use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` to make the current thread wait for one second. Do it only once, and you've got your "one-time timer".

Comment: So if I was decrementing the value of hunger by 10 every second, for 10 seconds, would I just keep repeating the TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1), 10 times?

Comment: Yes, this would be pretty much a straight-forward solution.

Comment: Also, I have one last issue if you can help me out with it. I would like to change the text of a JLabel temporarily while this is all going on. So the state of the JLabel would go from "hungry" to "well fed". However, I can't seem to change the JLabel from the action listener, on the JButton, even though the JLabel variable is public.

Comment: Make the JLabel private and write a synchronized method instead: `public synchronized void changeText(String newText){myLabel.setText(newText);}`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Working now!